# Instagram Graph Api Uploads Empty Content

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use graph api for upload reels videos to instagram. For some reason g. api uploads a empty video. it says "Processing video... Please try again later." but it is a legit 5sn video and never replaces with original one later.[the reels show up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NqHy.png)
this empty video contains my caption, people can like and comment as usual.

I upload videos to publit (a cloud) then share trough a link but i am %90 sure publit has nothing wrong.

Here is my code and thank you so much for your helps.

```py
class graph_api:

    def __init__(self, caption, fu_ig_user_id, fu_access_token, fu_video_url):

        self.ig_user_id = fu_ig_user_id
        self.access_token = fu_access_token
        self.video_url = fu_video_url
        self.caption = caption

    def publish_video(self, results):

        if 'id' in results:
            creation_id=results['id']
            second_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{}/media_publish'.format(self.ig_user_id)
            second_payload={
                            'creation_id':creation_id,
                            'access_token':self.access_token
                            }
            r=requests.post(second_url,data=second_payload)
            print(r.text)
            print('done')
        else:
            print('failed')

    def status_code(self, ig_conteiner_id):
        graph_url='https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/'
        url=graph_url+ig_conteiner_id
        param={}
        param['access_token']=self.access_token
        param['fields']='status_code'
        response=requests.get(url,params=param)
        response=response.json()
        return(response['status_code'])

    def upload_video(self):
        post_url="https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{}/media".format(self.ig_user_id)
        payload={
            'media_type':'REELS',
            'video_url' : self.video_url,
            'caption'   : self.caption,
            'access_token': self.access_token
        }

        r= requests.post(post_url,data=payload)
        print(r.text)
        results= json.loads(r.text)
        return(results)
    
    def main(self):
        results=self.upload_video()
        print('wait')
        time.sleep(10)

        ig_conteiner_id=results['id']
        
        
        while True:
            s=self.status_code(ig_conteiner_id)
            if s=='FINISHED':
                print('uploaded')
                self.publish_video(results)
                break
            else:
                print('wait')
                time.sleep(60)
```